# Why do macroscopic objects not move at the same speed their constituents are made of?

Tags: general-relativity, speed, elementary-particles

How can subatomic particles move at relativistic speeds while the things they make up are moving much slower?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: A human is not moving at the same speed of its electrons.

Comment: If you move around in a circle of radius $r$, no matter how fast you move, you’ll always be at distance $r$ from the centre.

Comment: And how do the football players run around at different speeds, but as a whole they stay on the pitch, and after an hour and a half they haven't gone miles away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an atom is of the order of $~\sim10^{-10}$m. That means the electron is most probable to be found within this range. So whatever dynamics the system might have, it will be bound within this range (especially if it’s in ground state which will be an energy eigenstate). So the system as a whole in general won’t have a net motion in any particular direction.

Comment: Do you mean the net momentum is zero?

Comment: Net average momentum is zero of the system. Yes.